# how to get the content of the file uploaded with input type file using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

Firstly sorry for my English.

How can i access the content of the file uploaded with HTML->Input type="file" tag in Jquery.

form code is:-

```
<div id="import_csv_dialog" style='display:none'>
        <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <table>
        <tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr><td>File Location:&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="file" id="file"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><a style="cursor:pointer" class="css_btn" onclick="importCsv()">Import</a></td></tr>
        </table>
        </form>
        </div>
```

**Jquery Code is: -**

```
function importCsv()
{
if($('#file').val()=="")
{
    jQuery.noticeAdd({
                    text: 'Please select a file',
                    type: 'error'
                });
    return;
}

var file_id=$('#file').val();
var url = "<?php echo $this->baseUrl; ?>/Ordermanagement/importcsv/"+file_id;
var data = {file_id: file_id};

$.post(url, data, function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)
{
    $('#gridList7').trigger("reloadGrid");
    jQuery.noticeAdd({
                      text: 'Data Imported successfully',
                      type: 'success'
                    });
    $('#import_csv_dialog').dialog('close');
});
```

}

In this code I am calling the zend controller function importcsv with the file name as the parameter. this is a .csv file. in this php file i will insert the content of this csv file to my database. But in this function, i am only able to get the file name as parameter, not the content or the path. how can i get the content of this file ? This is working the simple PHP with the help of $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]. How can i get the tmp_name  in Jquery.

Thanks very much

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740114/how-to-use-jquery-to-get-the-current-value-of-a-file-input-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `<script type="text/javascript">
>
>   $("#form_oferta").submit(function(event) {
>
>                       var dados = $( form ).serialize();
>
>                       $.ajax({
>
>                           type: "POST",
>
>                           contentType:attr( "enctype", "multipart/form-data" ),
>
>                           url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>adm/oferta_insert",
>
>                           data: dados,
>
>                           success: function( data )
>
>                           {
>
>                               alert( data );
>
>                           }
>
>                       });
>
>                       return false;
>
>                   }
>
>    </script>`

Comment: Actually i m new to this zend/Jquery. So please tell me where to write this code. Thanks

Comment: put this into the head section of your page and also include the min file of jquery

Comment: on the corner of a an answer click the above arrow sign and below these two arrows on hover u will see a tick mark so do both if you wish